# How to pass request parameters in the postman for this particular method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am trying to implement this spring application that I got from Github. I am still in the learning process so this might be a basic question. what parameters do I need to pass in the postman body for this update user method? I wrote { "id":1,"password":"1234"} in the postman body but its showing me 400 bad syntax error.

```
public void updateUser(int id, String parameter, String update)
    {
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        //System.out.print(mail);
         List<User_org> userList = userList();
         for(User_org i: userList)
         {
             User_org u= i;
             if(u.getId()==id)
             {
                 if(parameter.equalsIgnoreCase("mail"))
                 {   
                     u.setEmail(update);
                     session.update(u);
                     break;
                 }
                 if(parameter.equalsIgnoreCase("phone_no"))
                 {   
                     u.setPhone_num(Integer.parseInt(update));
                     session.update(u);
                     break;
                 }
                 if(parameter.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
                 {   
                     u.setPassword(update);
                     session.update(u);
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
        
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        //return id;
    }
```

In controller

```
public void updateUser(@RequestBody int id,String parameter, String updateToBe)
    {

        service.updateUser(id,parameter, updateToBe);
        
    }
```

Comment: Your request body is defined as `int id` which seems to be wrong. Add all the parameters to something like `ParametersDTO` and change updateUser signature to `updateUser(@RequestBody ParametersDTO parameteters)`

Comment: I never used ParametersDTO. Is there another way? Thank you for your response though.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Look at the example here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body

Answer (score 0):

Create an Entity or DTO with all fields
eg.

```
class User{
int id,
String parameter, 
String updateToBe

// getters and setters

}


public void updateUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {

        service.updateUser(user);
        
    }
```

From Postman send JSON object

Comment: But I have an Entity for users already. Here parameter I am passing is whether the user wants to change mail,phone_num, or password and updateToBe is a newly updated value.

Comment: Read this may be this is what you are trying to find [link]https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestparam-vs-pathvariable